# How to proove that geodesic is shortest path among all paths(not only smooth paths)

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose G is a geodesic and that P is a point on y. Prove that if
a point Q on the geodesic is sufficiently close to P, then the
segment PQ on G will be a shortest curve in comparison with all the
rectifiable curves (and not only with the piecewise smooth curves)
which join the points P and Q on the surface.
Prove that the segment PQ on the geodesic G is the only shortest
curve, joining the points P and Q on the surface, if the point Q is
sufficiently close to P.
This is question from book Pogorelov "Differential geometry" page 163.
I couldn't find proof of this in textbooks. If you can please provide any reference.
I think it is possible to approximate any rectifiable curve with smooth curve, but I don't know how to do it.

*Update*
I think it is possible to get proof that geodesic is shortest path among all paths, if to use lengths of inscribed polygons instead of integrals for path length!
Here is proof that geodesic is shortest of all smooth paths:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not true, right? Take two points close each other on the 2-sphere and join them with the geodesic going the long way around. Then, this is indeed not the shortest path. You need the additional condition that the geodesic is completely contained in a sufficiently small neighborhood of both points.

Comment: You can use the energy functional and uniqueness of geodesics. That might work well. "P sufficiently close to Q" means Q being in the injectivity radius of P.